# I would like to use a usb with vmware instead of virtual disk

Tags: usb, virtualbox, kvm-virtualization, vmware-workstation

Is there a way to install an os on usb using a virtual machine program? Open to other software, not just vmware.

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you want to make an install to a live USB, but want to use a VM to handle this.  You may find some assistance [here]https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing an OS to a USB drive, you should also be able to boot from USB to use it.

**For installing an OS to USB drive:**

For **VirtualBox**, instructions are available as an answer in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/).

For **VMware**, there is already an answer on how to do that in [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881556/install-ubuntu-on-external-hdd).

**For booting from USB in virtual machines:**

**VirtualBox** allows you to boot from USB drive. There is a good guide on how to doing that in [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/).

About **VMware**, it not possible normally. But there is a trick to do that, which is not recommended. You should use [Plop boot manager](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html). You can also find another guide on [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/97923/how-to-boot-a-vmware-virtual-machine-from-a-usb-drive/) for this trick.

It is recommended to use VirtualBox in such situation.

Comment: no i want to install to a usb not boot from it sorry for the confusion. i re-read and it is a bit confusing the way i put it

Comment: I misunderstood first. I've edited my answer to fit your needs. Please recheck that. ;)